LinkedIn : does LinkedInsight tag work if LinkedIn app to web ads and LinkedIn not connected in browser?
I’m running a LinkedIn campaign that directs users to my website. I would like to track users who click a specific button on my website, even if they initially clicked on an ad in the LinkedIn mobile app.
I’ve implemented the LinkedIn Insight Tag on my website and configured a conversion event triggered when users click the button.
However, I noticed that many LinkedIn mobile app users are not logged into LinkedIn when browsing via their mobile web browser.
My questions: Will the LinkedIn Insight Tag still function correctly in this scenario? Differently said: will the conversion event be sent to LinkedIn and correctly attributed to the user who clicked the ad in the LinkedIn app?
Thank you in advance for your help.
